# How to pass to bash function 2 variadic argument lists?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, variadic-functions

I'm looking for a way to abstract common command:

`find src app -name "*.hs" -exec grep -H "foo" \{\} \;`

to a bash/zsh function like:

`find $1 -exec grep -H $2 \{\} \;`

Above is not a solution as I'd like to pass lists of arguments for example with a given syntax: `findgrep "src -name '.hs'" "foo"`.
Here we could say that argument to grep is ever really going to be a single word and then pass the rest of argument list to find but there ought to be a more general way? Is there a way to sort of partial apply a bash function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot do that, as every individual argument is just a regular string; the shell has no distinct list type.

To pass two "groups" of arguments, you'll need to define some sort of "sentinel" that your function can recognize as such. For example,

```
findgrep () {
    args=()
    for x; do
        shift
        [[ $x == ::: ]] && break
        args+=("$x")
    done
    find "${args[@]}" -exec grep -H "$@" {} \;
}

findgrep src -name ".hs" ::: foo
```

`findgrep` will add arguments to the array `args` until it sees the argument `:::`, at which point it will ignore `:::` but stop iterating. Now you can use `args` as the first group of arguments to `find`, and whatever is left in `$@` as the second group.

Finding a valid sentinel could be difficult, as there's really no string that couldn't, in theory, also be a valid argument to `find`. An alternative would be to use an agreed-upon global array to store one or both sets.

```
findgrep () {
    find "${findgrepargs[@]}" -exec grep -H "$@" {} \;
}

findgrepargs=(src -name .hs)
findgrep foo
```

or to use a nameref to pass the name of an aribitary array to the function.

```
findgrep () {
    declare -n findargs=$1
    shift
    findgrep "${findargs[@]}" -exec grep -H "$@" {} \;
}

x=(src -name .hs)
findgrep x foo
```

Comment: I think the ergonomics is good, thanks for the solution! I'm so glad now I wasn't naming my files :::